# Webdriver poor performance on find_element

Tags: python, selenium

I have a page containing a table with 250 rows. For each row, I need to process some information and return some data. Here is how I am doing it now:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('mypage')
rows = driver.find_elements_by_css_path('table')
for row in rows:
    row.find_element_by_css_path('something')
    row.find_element_by_css_path('something else')
    etc.
```

Note that I am unable to use the pluralized `row`.`find_elements_by_css_path`, as each row I have I have to apply some logic to what I need to grab.

This is incredibly slow for me -- it takes about one minute to process the page. Doing the same with loading the html into beautiful soup takes about ten seconds, but gives me other errors, so I would like to stay 'within' selenium.

Is there a way to speed this up? I don't have control over the html, so I cannot change the css selectors to be using something like IDs.

Comment: How about something like row.find_element_by_xpath("//td[1]")   (from http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html)

Comment: First define the bottleneck - measure where the problem is and let us know. Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe its all about equal -- each 'find element' takes the same amount of time. For example, if each row-iteration takes 1s, each `find_element` takes about 1/3s.

Comment: @Hockey127 thanks, could you share the complete code you have and the link to a web-site you are testing against?